How do I make my angular signal reactive?
The following markup calls removeItemFromCart in the component to remove an item from the cart:
 <div>         
     <a class="d-block" style="color: red !important;"
       (click)="removeItemFromCart(item.product._id)">
       <i class="fa fa-trash">
       </i>&nbsp;Remove</a>
 </div>

removeItemFromCart in the component calls removeItemFromCart in the service:
public removeItemFromCart = (productId:string) => {
    this.cartService.removeItemFromCart(productId)
  }

This is the cart signal in CartService:
public cartSignal = signal<{ cartItems:CartItem[]}>({ cartItems:[]})

This is removeItemFromCart function in CartService:
public removeItemFromCart = (productId:string) => {
    const cartItems = this.cartSignal().cartItems.filter(item => item.product._id !== productId);
    this.cartSignal.set({cartItems:[...cartItems]});

    saveStateToLocalStorage(this.cartSignal())
  }

The removal of the item is not instantly reflected in the cart page. The target item remains on the page until the browser is refreshed.
Per request, html that uses the the result of the signal:
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-sm table-bordered">
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of cartItems">
            <td>
                <img class="img-fluid mb-2" src="assets/img/{{item.product.images[0]}}" style="width: 268px;">
            </td>
            <td>
                <h6 class="mb-2">{{item.product.name}}</h6>
                <div class="mb-2">
                    <span [createRatingStars]="item.product.rating">
                        <span>

                        </span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="text-end" style="text-align: right;">
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <h4 class="d-inline-block">
                        {{item.product.price | discountPrice:item.product.discount}}
                    </h4>
                    <small class="d-inline-block ms-2 text-decoration-line-through">
                        {{item.product.price | currency}}
                    </small>
                </div>
                <div class="d-sm-flex justify-content-sm-end mb-3" style="text-align: right;">
                    <div class="input-group text-center" style="width: 109.3px;">
                        <button class="btn btn-light btn-sm" type="button"
                            (click)="decreaseProductQuantity(item.product._id, item.quantity)"
                            style="border-color: #7b189f;">
                            <i class="fa fa-minus" style="color: #7b189f;">
                            </i>
                        </button>
                        <input class="form-control d-flex d-md-flex text-center" type="text" name="quantity"
                            [(ngModel)]="item.quantity" readonly="" style="border-color: #7b189f;">
                        <button class="btn btn-light btn-sm" type="button"
                            (click)="increaseProductQuantity(item.product._id)" style="border-color: #7b189f;">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus" style="color: #7b189f;">
                            </i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a class="d-block" style="color: #7b189f;">
                        <i class="fa fa-download">
                        </i>&nbsp;Save for later</a>
                    <a class="d-block" style="color: red !important;"
                        (click)="removeItemFromCart(item.product._id)">
                        <i class="fa fa-trash">

                        </i>&nbsp;Remove</a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

effect in the component that updates cartItems when signal changes in the service:
 private cartEffect = effect(() => {    
   this.cartItems = this.cartService.cartSignal().cartItems;
   console.dir('cartComponent.cartItems', this.cartItems)
 });


please share the HTML that uses this signal

@Naren have added the html and effect.

@NarenMurali's answer looks like it should fix the problem. I'd also just do cart = this.cartService.cartSignal in the component and @for(item of cart().cartItems; track $index) { ... } in your template (or track by the product id like in Naren's answer. No need for effect here and It's okay to read signals in templates. They were designed with this in mind.

I think the error might be due to the lack of trackBy, since you are using signals, you could use the new control flow syntax, which has a track by default. This might refresh the view, when the deletion happens.
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-sm table-bordered">
    <tbody>
      @for (item of cartItems; track item.product._id) {
        <tr>
          ...

